# Why can you call a copy constructor passing in the object you are constructing? (C++) (gcc)

Tags: c++, class, copy-constructor, member

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [std::string x(x);](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2529111/stdstring-xx)

```
class A {};

int main() {

    A a(a);
}
```

This compiles.

> gcc (GCC) 4.7.2 20120921 (Red Hat 4.7.2-2)
>   `g++ -o main main.cpp -Wall -w -ansi`

I receive no warnings.

Why does this appear to be valid C++?
Is this mentioned anywhere in the standard?
Are there warning flags that can report this for gcc?

When the class has member data, the data ends up random.
example:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {

public:
    int i;
    A() : i{6} {}
};

int main() {

    A a(a);
    std::cout << a.i << '\n';
}
```

> output: -482728464

What's going on here?
Also, how can I prevent myself from accidently doing this? - Is it possible to make it a compiler error?

Comment: Note the simpler example, `int i = i;`.

Comment: Clang 3.2 has recently reviewed its algorithm to detect such cases, you can check the [uninitialized.cpp](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/test/SemaCXX/uninitialized.cpp) file from the test suite to see all the cases in which it warns. Keep in mind that with gcc, the *uninitialized* warnings are potentially tied to the optimization level and may only be triggered for `O1` or `O2` builds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> (§ 3.3.2/1) The *point of declaration* for a name is immediately after its complete declarator (Clause 8) and before its *initializer* (if any), except as noted below. [ Example:
>
> ```
> int x = 12;
> { int x = x; }
> ```
>
> Here the second x is initialized with its own (indeterminate) value. —end example ]

This applies to user-defined types, such as your `class A`, as well. The copy constructor used is the default one, auto-generated by the compiler.